# Adding currency prefix to AmCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Hello fellow programmers ..
Im struggling adding a $ prefix to Amcharts
Has anyone had any experience adding currency format to AmCharts graphs?
So far I have tried many variations around the following with no success...

```
chart.numberFormatter = {
numberFormatter = numberPrefix="$";
};
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To add a prefix to value axis:

```
valueAxis.unit = "$";
valueAxis.unitPosition = "left";
```

In case you need this in a balloon, add it to balloonText:

```
graph.balloonText = "$[[value]]";
```

Comment: This answer is 100% effective

Answer (score 6):

For AmCharts v4 you can add a dollar sign using this:

```
chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = '$#,###';
```

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-numbers/

Answer (score 1):

As solution:
`chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = '$#,###';`

gives odd formatting for negative values (`$-500`),
a conditional formatting might comes handy:

```
chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = '$#,###s| -$#,###s';
```